# Calculating the length of a text in UNIX

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I have two questions:

1) I want to remove from my script every non-English letter
2) I want to calculate the length of a text, cleared from punctuation, spaces, etc. And I just do not know what is wrong with this part

Linux Script:

```
    #!/usr/bin/bash

awk '

BEGIN { FS="" } # defining a field separator in order to treat each character one by one
{
    $0 = tolower($0)    # removing case distinctions
    gsub(/[[:punct:]]/,"", $0) # removing every punctuation mark
    gsub(/\ /, "", $0) # removing spaces
    gsub(/[0-9]/, "", $0) # removing digits
    gsub(/![a-z]/, "", $0) # removing every non-English letter <- This does not work

    #After the removing of every possible punctuation mark, space, digit and non-English
    #letter in the user-defined text, we calculate the occurence of each character and place into an array



    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
        {
          freq[$i]++
          length++
        }

}
```

But it shows me the following error:
awk: cmd. line 17:        length++
awk: cmd. line 17:                ^ unexpected newline or end of string

Please help me with at least the second question. I just do not what is wrong, everything seems alright. Thanks beforehand !

Comment: A negated character class is `[^a-z]` not `![a-z]`. Also you don't need multiple `gsub` calls for that spaces, digits and punctuation are all "non-letters".

Comment: Also, you can use the [`length()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#String-Functions) function instead of counting the number of remaining letters.

Comment: Do you literally mean "English letters" or do you mean "Alphabetic characters"? Although they are PROBABLY the same in text written in English, there can be a big difference in general and there is no support in awk for the former AFAIK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`awk`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html)

```
awk '{gsub("[^A-Za-z]", "");i+=length}END{print i}'
```

Using [`tr`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tr.html) and [`wc`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/wc.html)

```
tr -C -d "A-Za-z" | wc -c
```

They both delete all characters not in the range `A-Za-z`, then count the remaining characters. The [`tr`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tr.html) one has the advantage, or disadvantage, of being dependent on your locale.

You can also create an [`awk`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) script the same way you create a shell script.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk
    { gsub("[^A-Za-z]", ""); i+=length }
END { print i }
```

For maximum portability you either need to set the locale in your script to `POSIX`, or list out every character.

```
tr -C -d "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" | wc -c
```

Comment: A-Za-z can include non-letters in some locales, use `[:alpha:]` instead. Also the first arg for gsub() is an RE so use RE delimiters not string delimiters unless you are doing string concatenation with a variable or have some other very specific need and understand the caveats..

Comment: @EdMorton [`[:alpha:]`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/xbd_chap07.html#tag_07_03_01) can match non english characters, the original question wanted to count only english letters. The most portable way would, probably, be to list all the letters out `ABCD..Zabc..wxyz`.

Comment: Correct about [:alpha:] vs English letters, I mentioned that issue in my comment under the OPs question. Yes, listing the individual letters might be what's needed if the OP really needs only English letters but setting the locale correctly should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this MAY be what you want (uses GNU awk for multi-char RS)

```
awk -v RS='[[:alpha:]]' 'END{print (NR?NR-1:0)}' file
```

e.g.:

```
$ cat file
a
    b,c
  d3e
$ awk -v RS='[[:alpha:]]' 'END{print (NR?NR-1:0)}' file
5
```